# How to access to txpool within a web3 script?

Tags: go-ethereum, txpool

I run a testnet Ropsten (revival) ethereum node. I would like to get the content of txpool. With a geth console, I can access the variable txpool.

My question is how can I access this variable within a web3 script ?

```
Web3 = require("web3");
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

Someting like the following:

```
pendingTx = web3.txpool ?

pendingTx = web3.eth.txpool ?
```

they are all undefined...

Comment: you are right web3.txpool is returning undefined. Looks like this API is unavailable.

Comment: When we launch geth with rpcapi and ipcapi, we can specify txpool as an option:
--rpcapi "eth,web3,txpool"
--ipcapi "admin,db,eth,miner,net,shh,txpool,web3"
Are they useful for something ?

Comment: Yes, I defined txpool while starting geth node but still web3.txpool returns undefined.

Comment: The `--XXXapi` only enables the server side api to be available. On the client side you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3admin, to extend the normal web3 with extra methods. But some methods are still missing and you have to add them by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Web3 1.0.0 it's easy to implement it yourself:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('ws://127.0.0.1:8546');
web3.eth.extend({
  property: 'txpool',
  methods: [{
    name: 'content',
    call: 'txpool_content'
  },{
    name: 'inspect',
    call: 'txpool_inspect'
  },{
    name: 'status',
    call: 'txpool_status'
  }]
});
```

Then use it normally:

```
web3.eth.txpool.status().then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

Output:

```
{pending: "0x0", queued: "0x0"}
```

The same way you can [extend](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html#extend) Web3 to invoke any other "missing" [JSON RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#list-of-management-apis).

Comment: Found this strange behavior, Method name `content` is not working, while others are working.

Comment: I'm using infura and it can't resolve these functions.

Comment: Can you tell, is there any way to subscribe to txpool? so, not just one-time polling event, but got a websocket/realtime one (considering that we have a standard WS provider).