# Easy way to get txpool?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, txpool

Update! 
I have my node running with `geth --rpcapi txpool --rpc`

`var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));
console.log(web3.txpool);`

I still receive

```
undefined
```

With

```
web3.eth.extend({   property: 'txpool',   methods: [{
    name: 'content',
    call: 'txpool_content'   },{
    name: 'inspect',
    call: 'txpool_inspect'   },{
    name: 'status',
    call: 'txpool_status'   }] });
web3.eth.txpool.content().then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

I am still getting only `{ pending: '0x0', queued: '0x0' }`

How can this be? I'd expected hundreds of transactions.

Comment: I think you're confusing Python and JavaScript. The documentation you're reading is for a Python library, but you seem to be writing JavaScript code.

Comment: @carver I tried the solutions proposed there... but it is not working out

Comment: If there are no good answers to an existing question, creating another question just adds noise. Try upvoting that question, commenting on it, or even clarifying the question with an update.

Comment: Solved by waiting for eth.syncing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your node you must doit with 
    --rpcapi txpool

Comment: I think you are right, I am just trying to figure out how to use the data which I am getting by starting the node this way.

Comment: I tried `var Web3 = require('web3');
var Web4 = require('web3');

web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/Whm5Ks3VGzJMBGHh4MEx'));
var web4 = new Web4(Web4.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8546");`, However, `console.log(web4.txpool);` still gives me `undefined`

Comment: I tried `geth --rpcapi txpool --rpc` together with `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));` 
and
`geth --wsapi txpool --ws` together with `var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'ws://some.local-or-remote.node:8546');`

Doesn't work for me

Comment: try with geth --rpc --rpcapi txpool,web3,net,eth

Answer (score 1):

The web3.py docs (for connecting with Python) are not interchangeable for web3.js docs (for connecting with JavaScript). They have different APIs.

Web3.js appears to not have a built-in mechanism for querying transaction pool (likely because the geth and parity approaches are different). See this answer for adding your own pool API: [How to access to txpool within a web3 script?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24127/how-to-access-to-txpool-within-a-web3-script)

Comment: I did this, however I don't get any results. Updated my post to reflect this